# ColdFusion Can't Impersonate Windows Users to Access Directory Sizes - Maybe ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, coldfusion, active-directory

We have ColdFusion and Active Directory running within the same domain. I'm trying to write a script that ColdFusion can run to get the sizes of client directories within the file system. However, each directory requires different windows authentication.

ColdFusion `<cfdirectory>` doesn't have a means to impersonate the user for each directory. Using the JavaIO is also apparently not useful as Java apparently doesn't know anything about the Windows authentication.

I found a suggestion for using APS.NET to write a COM or .NET component, but the article didn't go any further. I have since googled my heart out and not found anything more useful.

If anyone has any information or assistance to offer, you can't imagine my gratitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to build an ASP.net application which will access the individual client directories using in-built windows authentication to return file sizes and other data and dump them into a database. We will use windows scheduler to schedule the running of this application. ColdFUsion will be used merely to manipulate the data into reports.

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion will, by default, run as the Local System account. This account will not have access to the network.

I would suggest running the ColdFusion service with a domain account that has read access to the client directories and you should then be able to use `cfdirectory`.

[You may find this blogpost helpful.](http://www.codfusion.com/blog/post.cfm/running-cf-under-a-domain-account)

Comment: If you run it as Administrator it can access any directory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is that each directory in question requires a different set of user permissions. So he's right I think. CF can't "impersonate" each user - though I'm not sure that I know of a system that can do that. would you have to store separate permissions for each directory? Ask for a password for each one?

I don't think you can "impersonate" an AD account without creating appropriate tokens using the key infrastructure right? So that means you have to store username and passwords to "authenticate" with. I think storing and using such "impersonate" information would  certainly negates any security enhancements you hoped to gain from using a different user for each directory.

Architecturally you are better off running CF as an AD user with "read" permissions to the directories in question - then you can access the size information you are looking for but would still not be able to modify the files within the directory. That's my take.

Comment: We don't want to mess with the ColdFusion service if possible. It's looking like we'll be going down the ASP.NET path (no idea how just at the moment) with CF just kicking off the process.